Hibernating between dual booted windows 11 and windows 10
I have a dual boot between windows 10 and 11, both on separate disks and both using bitlocker.
I want to be able to hibernate and switch between versions without losing state.
Can this be achieved using grub? What is suggested way of achieving this functionality?

No, it can't. When you hibernate one you'll wake up that one.

Why Grub? There are already questions on this site about dual-booting Windows and Hibernation.

This question is similar to: Is it possible to enable hibernation when dual booting Windows?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Yeah, not possible. What you could consider is running Linux as your OS, then inside it install something like VirtualBox, VMWare, etc, and run the windows installs in there. With that software, you can save its state to disk, which is similar to hibernation, and you can swap between. The downside is the performance loss. Alternatively, you can use one of the two OSses as your main, and run the other OS virtually using VirtualBox, etc.
